# How to enable/disable button before&after choosing files in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a list of rows which shows selected files. I have to enable close button when choosing a file and should disable when the file gets deleted. Could you please suggest me to achieve it. Thanks in advance

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let region of regions;let i = index;">
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 fileNameTruncater">
            <label class="terms" placement="bottom" ngbTooltip="{{region}}" container="body"
                         tooltipClass="my-custom-class" style="
                         margin-left: 20px;">{{region}}</label>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-0">
            <button class="fa fa-download" type="button" id="download"/>
        </div> 

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <app-file-upload #lanesFile (emitFile)="lanesFileInput($event)" id="choose_file"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-0">
            <button class="fa fa-upload"  
                    type="button" id="upload"/>
        </div> 

        <div class="col-sm-0">
            <button class="fa fa-times" type="button" (click)="reset(i)" id="delete"/>
        </div> 

        <div class="col-sm-0">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle" style="color:rgb(12, 131, 115);margin-left: 5px;">
                <!-- icon -->
            </i>
        </div> 

    </div>
</div>
```

**TypeScript file**

```
public laneFileNameExists = false;
public myFiles = Array<File>();
formData: FormData = null;

lanesFileInput(file: File) {
    console.log('On File Change event..');
    // const inputEl: HTMLInputElement = this.inputEl.nativeElement;
    this.formData = new FormData();
    this.myFiles.push(file);
    this.formData.append('file', file, 'lane.xlsx');
    this.laneFileNameExists = true;
}
```

Can you please suggest me how to find that specific row attached any files or not.

Comment: What about passing the template variable (`#lanesFile`) to the `lanesFileInput` and use it as the key to keep track of the File data inside a `Map<File>` instead of an array (as you're doing). Then, on the template you could pass that map as a parameter to a `pipe` to verify if the template varibable exists as a key on the map (if so, you can do whatever you want to)

Comment: @jpavel Thanks for the response. Will try it and let u know